# i want to show two cell in one row in uicollectionview in all iphone model

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uicollectionview

[here is some snap of it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tP9yg.jpg)  i tried with this code but it's not working:

my collecionview cell :

size is      : 166 : 32
   Min Spacing  :  10 : 10

section insets: 20 : 20

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt
        indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize
    {
        if collectionView == MainCollectionView
        {
            let padding : CGFloat =  50
            let collectionViewSize = MainCollectionView.frame.size.width - padding

            return CGSize(width: collectionViewSize/2, height: collectionViewSize/2)

        }
        return CGSize(width: 0, height: 0)
    }
```

Comment: You can use two cell in one section.

Answer (score 0):

Use UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout in your view
and call the delegate method

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let width = self.view.frame.width
    return CGSize(width: (width)/2, height: (width)/2) // width & height are the same to make a square cell
}
```

Comment: have you set collection delegate by self

Answer (score 0):

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize{

    let width = (collectionView.frame.width/2)-0.5
    return CGSize(width:width , height: width)

}
```

Comment: in which direction the scroll is

Comment: direction the scroll is vertical

Answer (score 0):

Try implementing these `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` `delegate methods` to achieve the desired result:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize
{
    return CGSize(width: (collectionView.bounds.width - 10 - 20*2)/2, height: collectionView.bounds.height)
    //In collectionView.bounds.width - 10 - 20*2 :
    //10 for cell spacing and 
    //20*2 for section insets on left and right
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat
{
    return 10
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets
{
    return UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 20, bottom: 0, right: 20)
}
```

Specify your requirements more clearly so that I can help you further.

Comment: What is not working? Show the output that you are getting and what you want to achieve.

Comment: i want to arrange two cell in one row in uicolectionview.

Comment: Are you using horizontal or vertical collection view?

Comment: Add the screenshot if you can for better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is perfect but the delegate method you are using is perhaps not getting called. Based on the swift syntax version you are using, try the latest delegate method. And also make sure that you have made your collection view the observer of that delegate by making it self.

Comment: i am only having problem with 5s adn bellow it phone. according to me i am using updated syntax if you have any suggestion please help me.

Comment: Problem is device specific or iOS version specific ?